# Text direction with print or println in Swift for mixed text

Tags: ios, swift, right-to-left, hebrew

I am attempting to print a string with a hebrew character "א - aleph is a silent..." using println or print functions in Swift. The simple code below has an output with the first character printed right-to-left (RTL) and the rest of the text left-to-right (LTR). How can I change this so it is all printed LTR.

Thanks in advance.

```
var content:String="\u{05D0} - aleph is a silent consonant - however it is pronounced as a, o, e, i or u based on the vowel used."

println(content)
```

Output should be:

```
א - aleph is a silent consonant - however it is pronounced as a, o, e, i or u based on the vowel used.
```

However the hebrew character is printed on the right of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I found the answer. Adding "\u{200E}", the Left to Right Mark before the character resolves the issue.

More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: and "\u{202B}" for Right To Left