# Forcing label text to left-to-right while including some right-to-left text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string `د.إ.` that represent a currency symbol and that I get from `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_AE").objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol) as! String`

In my `UILabel`, when I set the text to `theSymbol + aNumber` (I cannot even write it down here, it gets reversed as well), it is displayed as  `aNumber + theSymbol` as most probably the symbol is made of strings that should be displayed right-to-left.

How can I force my label to display this left-to-right, whatever the symbol is?

Comment: Are you setting the direction of text for the UILabel, or you're saying it is doing it from the String source? Couldn't you just program `aNumber + theSymbol`, thus spitting out the opposite?

Comment: I'm not setting any direction anywhere. It's the default behaviour. The problem is that I get some normal LTR symbols such as $, €, ... If I set the text to `aNumber + theSymbol` it will reverse it won't change it for LTR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to make it work:

```
label.text = "\u{202A}" + symbol + "\u{202C}" + "1234"
```

`\u{202A}` is for Left-to-Right Embedding and `\u{202C}` is for Pop-Directional-Formatting.

[Here](http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/) is a good article about bidirectional text

Answer (score 0):

I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187417/text-direction-with-print-or-println-in-swift-for-mixed-text) is the answer. Add \u{200E} before your currency symbol. I don't understand it but it works.

Comment: I saw that before but it doesn't work when I do `label.text = "\u{200E}" + symbol + "1234"`

Comment: Did you try `"\u{200E}\\(symbol)1234" or some other combination written within one string instead of using + ?